# sticky="W" not aligning text to left side of window while using Tkinter's .grid() function in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

When I use `.read()` to read a text file and then I assign the text to a Tkinter `label` and pack it into a window using `.grid(row, column, sticky="W")`, the text does not get aligned to the left of the window. Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
instructions_file = open("instructions.txt")
instructions = tk.Tk()
instructions.title("Instructions")
instruction_lbl = tk.Label(
                master=instructions,
                text=instructions_file.read()
                ).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
```

I checked this code several times but I can't figure out what's going wrong. `sticky="W"` should align the text to the left side of the window, but it does nothing, as if it wasn't even there. Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think what you need is adding `justify='left'` to `tk.Label(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Justify Left for aligning text to left and anchor left for aligning the whole label to left. anchor="w", justify='left' inside label creation not in the grid.

```
import tkinter as tk
instructions_file = open("instructions.txt")
instructions = tk.Tk()
instructions.title("Instructions")
instruction_lbl = tk.Label(
                master=instructions,
                text=instructions_file.read(), anchor="w", justify='left'
                ).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
```